# How can I get Authentication Key for Rakuten?

Tags: api, authentication, rms

I am developing a web application for Rakuten.com .
I found their documentation in https://developers.rakuten.com/ but for using Rakuten RMS API I need an authentication key.

Is there an another way for using this API without authentication key (like a demo api)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support request that should be directed at the company. See [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Rakuten.com in the US then you can email us at merchants@marketplace.rakuten.com.  We will be able to answer any questions from merchants and developers.

If you this request is for any other country then you will need to proceed with the advice Stelian has provided.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you are trying to access there are purely for Rakuten merchants (people that sell their products on the Rakuten marketplaces). This means, that in order to get an API key, you either are a merchant or work for one.

In case you are doing some development for one of our merchants, please contact him for an API key.